# Converting data from a column to a date in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of 50s of dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(d1 = c (1,2,3),
                  d2 = c ("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03"))

df2 <- data.frame(d1 = c (11,22,33, 56),
                  d2 = c ("43877", "43878", "43879", "43880"))

df3 <- data.frame(d1 = c (0.1,0.2,0.3),
                  d2 = c ("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"))

dff <- list (df1, df2, df3)
```

The second column in some data frames is not a date. This column is text which, when converted to a number format, can be converted to a date, as per the following idea:

```
  d2 <- as.numeric(d2),
  d2 <- as.Date(d2, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

How to make a change in those df2 columns where such a change is necessary? I know that you need to apply some form of apply and a conditional conversion depending on the datatype in the df2 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(dff, \(x) {
   if(all(grepl("^\\d+$", x$d2))) {
  x$d2 <- as.Date(as.numeric(x$d2), origin = "1899-12-30")} else 
      x$d2 <- as.Date(x$d2); x})
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  d1         d2
1  1 2021-01-01
2  2 2021-01-02
3  3 2021-01-03

[[2]]
  d1         d2
1 11 2020-02-16
2 22 2020-02-17
3 33 2020-02-18
4 56 2020-02-19

[[3]]
   d1         d2
1 0.1 2022-01-01
2 0.2 2022-01-02
3 0.3 2022-01-03
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
map(dff,  ~.x %>% 
    mutate(d2 = coalesce(ymd(d2), excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(d2)))))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  d1         d2
1  1 2021-01-01
2  2 2021-01-02
3  3 2021-01-03

[[2]]
  d1         d2
1 11 2020-02-16
2 22 2020-02-17
3 33 2020-02-18
4 56 2020-02-19

[[3]]
   d1         d2
1 0.1 2022-01-01
2 0.2 2022-01-02
3 0.3 2022-01-03
```

Comment: I liked the use of `coalesce` instead of using `if_else`.

Comment: I don't know why the \ character precedes the expression (x)?
Does all (grepl("^\\d+$", x$d2)) refer to and mean all values in a column?
Regardless, the solution is great and it works. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @GrBa It is a lambda expression.  You can also use `function(x)`

Answer (score 2):

Use transform on each component of dff with the indicated expression. No packages are used.

```
lapply(dff, transform, d2 = if (any(grepl("-", d2))) as.Date(d2) else
  as.Date(as.numeric(d2), origin = "1899-12-30"))
```